# VSE Transform Position attribute integer value workaround (2.93)

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, interpolation

I just realized that in Blender 2.93 VSE strip transform position attribute is an integer value (pixel value as the picture shows below).

[image]

Because of that animating the position results a stop/stepped motion as the animation curve shows:

[image]

Is there a setting or a workaround to solve that? Previous versions of Blender have float value for position. That meant the position animation was interpolated/filtered.

Comment: Could you please clarify re which property you are animating above, is it [`ranslate_start_x`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.91/bpy.types.TransformSequence.html#bpy.types.TransformSequence.translate_start_x)  or [`offset_x`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.93/bpy.types.SequenceTransform.html#bpy.types.SequenceTransform.offset_x)

Comment: I added a picture about the UI. These are the offset_x and y.